# android admob button

Tags: android, button, admob

Can't figure this one out. I have five buttons and the 5th I want to display my AdMob advertisement however it simply will not work. I'm so close! Any assistance appreciated. Below is my activity.java and my main.xml

```
package com.CompanyName.SANDBOX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.ads.*;

public class SANDBOXActivity extends Activity { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //--> Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e27391701ceb");
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    Button btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Button05);
    // Add the adView to it
    btn5.addView(adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    //--> End AdMoB adView
}
}
```

and my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerInside">
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_Button01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Start SANDBOX Mobile">
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_Button02" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="More Applications">
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_Button03" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Share">
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_Button04" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="Send feedback">
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_Button05"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
</Button>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error if any do you receive?

Comment: no error at all, it simply does not display any ad of any type

Comment: Are you sure you have the permission to access the internet?

Comment: yes - I have the line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in my manifest.xml

Comment: I copied your code in eclipse and it gave me this error   The method addView(AdView) is undefined for the type Button  try making the button a View instead of a button.

Comment: will have to cancel the question all together. Admob updated their jar / package to v4.1.1 has apparently hasn't updated their support page or instructions. Even the .zip file is incomplete and doesn't have the correct instructions.

Comment: have you tried to run ads in test mode?

Answer (score 1):

There is no addView(AdView) method for Button.Change the button to a layout.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lout);
// Create the adView
    final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e27391701ceb");
   // Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

request.setTesting(true);
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView1);
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
re.setTesting(true);
adview.loadAd(re);
```

Probably try to import these, hope it will helps.
You need to make it for your app. I couldn't make it too first :)

Comment: "When you say try to import these", What do you mean? I believe I may have found out the problem lies with AdMob. Apparently, there's a significant bug in the version AdMob just pushed out LIVE to PRODUCTION on July 19th! The admob jar 
is only about 50K in size and the .zip itself does not contain the instructions or pdf. See the following URL. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/Ys6CsvTez3I. I personally have already put in approximately 25 hours attempting to resolve the issue.